# Uploading "Media File" binary content via the Apex Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, attachment, content, upload

I have a SalesForce Entity that I'm trying to upload via the Data Loader.

So far we've been able to successfully upload all the "meta data" on the object but have been unsuccessful in actually uploading the attached file.

What I want to know is. "Is it actually possible to upload this binary content through Data Loader"

Below is a screen shot of the web interface to upload the object. As you can see all the key message detail fields appear at the top, and then the media information is in a seperate section below. If I edit the layout of this page, this media file area is a "VisualForce Pages > Media File"

[image: Salesforce Web UI]

When we attempt to do an Upsert via the Data Loader GUI, we specify our Upsert CSV, and then perform our column mappings. See below, it would seem that while the KeyMessage does expose properties for Media File Name, Size & CRC, it doesn't expose an explicit property for the actually binary data that the file would be stored in.

[image: Key Message Properties]

The latest version of the Data Loader User Guide does make reference to uploading "Content Files" (See Page 14 - http://na11.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf)

However this section refers to supplying "VersionData" and "PathOnClient" params in the CSV as well as using a snippet of salesforce API calls to establish your record types, but I can't figure out how this applies to our object (Key Message) as there aren't any columns to in our Key Message Object to map to.

Comment: What field type are you intending as the place to store this? Can you also show a screen shot of your object metadata? Normally we don't store file content directly in a field, it is attached to the record somehow, either through the chatter feed, an attachment record, or in content as you read about in the Data Loader Guide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter... this is exactly what I'm struggling to find out. I can't figure out what entity/object that the media file backs on to. I've scoured the list of entity types in list in the export screen of the dataloader but don't see anything that looks relevant. Total SF newbie here so any pointer on how I could figure this out would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably this is a custom object.

Comment: yes. it's part of a product called Veeva CRM

Comment: I think you'll need to inspect that object with something that gives you more details such as workbench. Presumably that will show which relationships are being used and hopefully provide details as to which object is storing that. Of course...maybe their documentation or support can give you some help as to how to upload that using a data management tool.

Comment: Ok will investigate `Workbench` and get back to you